# How to develop number sense while finding out the middle/median value?

Tags: statistics, mental-arithmetic

I have seen that many people can find out the middle value between numbers orally. My question is how to find the middle value orally? For example , the middle value between -

24576.5 MHz — 24881.5 MHz

Please don't tell me $\frac{24576.5 + 24881.5}{2}$. I am looking for the way to tackle these problems mentally.

Comment: Pick a number in between and let if follow by a short prayer.

Comment: In your example, you could reduce the problem to the problem of finding the average between 576 and 881. The difference is easy to calculate: 305. This leads to 576 + 152.5 = 728.5 as average. Added to 24000.5, you arrive at 24729